# Find uniq items in column of gzip file

Tags: sorting, gzip, unique

I want to return the number of unique items in one column of my gzip file. 
To sort on a normal file I know you can use something like:

`sort -u -t, -k1,1 filename | wc -l`

but when I run this on a gzip file I get:

`?BC??\ks?ʑ???`

Is it possible to change this format to find the unique items in a column, given a gzip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I actually figured it out!

`gzcat vcf_del.vcf.gz | cut -f 2 | sort | uniq | wc -l` (and zcat also works)

Then if there are parts of the file you do not want (for instance in VCF files there are a series of lines with "#") you can simply remove them as such:

`gzcat vcf_del.vcf.gz | awk '!/^#/{print $0}' | cut -f 2 | sort | uniq | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

The `gzip` package comes with the `zcat` program which works just like `cat` but works on gz files.

```
zcat filename | sort -u -t -k1,1
```

Comment: So I think the command is actually `gzcat filename | sort -u -t -k1,1`.

Comment: glad to hear it :) if this solved your problem you should accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

you cannot run search and sort commands on compressed file either you have to extract compressed file and then run you commands on output of the gzip command.

you can try below command

```
gunzip -c filename | sort -u -t -k1,1
```

Comment: This seems to unzip the file, correct? I simply want to view the sort, not change the file itself.

Comment: This will cat content of your file inside gz file and print sort. It is not going to modify your file.